# How can i generate dynamic columns in mysql using PL/SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the table structure as follows:

## Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE unit_names (unit_id INT(3), unit_names VARCHAR(20) );
INSERT INTO unit_names VALUES (1,'UNIT-1');
INSERT INTO unit_names VALUES (2,'UNIT-2');
INSERT INTO unit_names VALUES (3,'UNIT-3');
```

## Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE items (item_id INT(3), unit_id INT(3), price INT(3), date_time date);
INSERT INTO items VALUES(1,1,1,'1980-06-01');
INSERT INTO items VALUES(2,1,3,'1981-06-01');
INSERT INTO items VALUES(3,2,2,'1980-06-01');
INSERT INTO items VALUES(4,3,5,'1983-06-01');
INSERT INTO items VALUES(5,3,5,'1983-07-01');
```

What i am trying to achieve is the following output from the above is

[image: output Image]

I clearly have no idea how to write a PL/SQL query for this.  I have trouble with the logic for achieving the result.

Just curious:
Is it possible to attain the same result by just using query.

I know my question is board. But any information would be helpful for me.

Comment: What database are you using?  That is not a valid `CREATE TABLE` statement in Oracle.

Comment: i am using mysql database.

Comment: Then you cannot use pl/sql.and if you are using a tutorial or other reference for pl/sql then you need to put it to one side because mysql is very different. In this case I think you should be searching for mysql prepared statements, myslq pivot and mysql conditional aggregation.